# Eliminar elemento del DOM y Lista con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quisiera eliminar el registro que subo mediante una img X, cuando subo el archivo este se realiza bien, mostrando un span con el nombre del archivo en un label

```
"<span>"+urls[i].split('/').pop()+"<a id="+idMinuta+" href=\"javascript:EliminaRegistro();\"><img src=\"/sites/gadt/direcciones/dc/contabilidad/fape/SiteAssets/img/btn-borrar.png\" ></a>";
```

para poder eliminar el registro necesito el id, el cual se encuentra en el `<a>`
trate de poner un evento click en el $(document).ready, pero no me funciona.

```
 $("img").click( function (event) {
                 alert();
    });
```

la función EliminaRegistro(); solo llama a la función definitiva que elimina el registro

Comment: Hola @elsa ;) ¿El link lo que hará es eliminar el span padre? ¿o solo quires limpie el contenido?

Comment: Redacta mejor tu pregunta, no es my entendible. Usa las comas y puntos por favor

Comment: @MitsuGami limpia el contenido, como a su vez elimina el registro de las Lista

Comment: Proporciona un poco más de detalles, como **qué es** un registro y en **dónde está** tu lista.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar:

```
$("img").click( function (event) {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Esto lo que hace es buscar el contenedor del contenedor del 'img' al que se le ha hecho click y eliminarlo. En tu caso eliminirá el elemento .

Comment: ¿estás seguro que quiere eliminar el `span`?

Comment: @MitsuGami si tiene que desaparecer de la casilla la información (nombre del archivo, botón eliminar)

Answer (score 0):

Añade a la función `eliminaRegistro` el parámetro `event`:

```
<a onclick="return eliminaRegistro(event)">...</a>
```

En tu función, obtén el padre del anchor (guíate de tu anterior pregunta si aún no te acostumbras a `Event`):

```
function eliminaRegistro(ev) {
  ev.target.parentNode.remove();
}
```

- `ev.target`: el anchor
- `.parentNode`: el padre del anchor, osea, el `span`.
- `.remove()`: función que tienen los elementos HTML para auto eliminarse del DOM.

O hacerlo directamente vía jQuery:

```
$('.elimina-registro').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).parent().remove();
}
```

Donde `.elimina-registro` son los anchors para eliminar los registros (suponiendo que tienes varios), ya que si lo haces por `id` y todos tienen el mismo `id` no tendrás el comportamiento esperado.

Comment: ya mira, el tema de borrar el elemento del DOM, lo dejare para el ultimo, lo que necesito mas urgente es traerme el id que esta en el <a>, ya que con eso puedo eliminar el elemento de la Lista (en como una tabla en una bd pero en Sharepoint), entonces trato de capturar el id pero no he podido

Comment: @elsa tan simple como: `$(this).id`. Recuerda que `$(this)` hace referencia al elemento que originó el evento, osea el anchor (`a`).

Comment: no funciona, lo puse ´var id = $(this).id;´ , pero sale undefined

Comment: @elsa. Estás usando la forma de `eliminarRegistro(event)` o la de `jQuery`. Si usas la primera, entonces debes usar `ev.target.id`.

Comment: ocupo EliminaRegistro(event) lo recibe function EliminaRegistro(ev){
 
 var id = ev.target.id;
  alert(id);  
}

pero muestra : No se puede obtener la propiedad 'target' de referencia nula o sin definir

Comment: Eso pasa porque en el `a` no has pasado el parámetro `event`. Mira el ejemplo que te puse: `<a onclick="return eliminaRegistro(event)">...</a>`.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46304/discussion-between-mitsu-gami-and-elsa).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes Usar [remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) para eliminar elementos del `DOM` y  [parent](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) para acceder al elemento padre que lo contiene (Así eliminar el SPAN)
Además recordar para accedes a los atributos de un elemento  del dom puedes hacerlo con [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```js
$(function(){ 
   $('span a').click(function(e) {
 $(this).parent('span').remove();
 var id = $(this).attr('id');
 alert(id);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
    <a  class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Eliminar</a>
    <img src="assets/img/im1.jpg" alt="" width="50" height="50">
  </span>
```

> $(this) es lo mismo que $('span a'), ya que es el elemento que provocó el evento click .

Comment: ocupo el $(this) en vez de $('#remove'), ya que se desconoce el id de a, pero cuando laza el alert dice que es undefined

Comment: En tu ejemplo se ve un id en la etiqueta a , ese id se está tomando como referencia. si tu etiqueta no tiene id , saldrá el mensaje de undefined

Comment: claro, en el ejemplo tiene un id, pero si te fijas es una variable entonces necesito la información que trae esa variable, es por ello que necesito capturarlo, es un valor desconocido

Comment: Modifiqué mi Javascript, probar y me comenta :)